# random image from google set as background using query for image keyword

Tags: javascript, image, random, google-image-search

i have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    var search;

    //i suggest instead of this to make keywords list so first to pick random keyword than to do search and pick random image
    var keyword = 'cute kittens';

    function OnLoad()
    {
        search = new google.search.ImageSearch();

        search.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

        search.execute(keyword);
    }

    function searchComplete()
    {
        if (search.results && search.results.length > 0)
        {
            var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * search.results.length);

            //you will probably use jQuery and something like: $('body').css('background-image', "url('" + search.results[rnd]['url'] + "')");
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + search.results[rnd]['url'] + "')";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

it is supposed to give me a picture of a kitten then make that the background, however it is not giving me any background, does anybody have an idea on how to fix this? if you do, please help. this may seem like a duplicate, however i got the code from a previous post and it does not work, so please do not mark as duplicate, i have tried modifying the code in multiple ways, none worked, i lost the different edits when my device shut down so i dont have those. (i was a bad developer and didnt save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the API has been deprecated since 2011. Google has likely shut off the service completely as their deprecation policy allows them to do so under one of the following clauses

**Google reserves the right in its discretion to cease providing all or any part of the Deprecated Version of the Services immediately without any notice if:**

- providing the Deprecated Version of the Services could create a substantial economic burden as determined by Google in its reasonable good faith judgment; or
- providing the Deprecated Version of the Services could create a security risk or material technical burden as determined by Google in its reasonable good faith judgment.

https://developers.google.com/terms/deprecation

I put your code in a JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zcthpd4L/6/ and was met with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImageSearch' of undefined
at OnLoad ((index):52)
at (index):70
```

This doesn't appear to be due to a configuration issue, and is likely due to the service no longer being available. Your best bet is to use the custom search api: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: any idea as to how to do this with a custom api? i am not good with js

Comment: Here's the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction